# Dapper returns different column name

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dapper

I'm using Dapper to make a select in the database and the return shows the name of the columns differently.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Image below, left(JSON returns from API), right(SQL Server Table)

**JSON result:**

[image: JSON result]

---

**C# code:**

Controller Method

```
IEnumerable<Romaneio> romaneios;
string query = "SELECT * FROM TB_ROMANEIOS";
romaneios = await connection.QueryAsync<Romaneio>(query)
```

The Class used by Dapper

```
public class Romaneio
{
    public string ROMANEIO_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUTO_ID { get; set; }
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public string QTD_PALLET { get; set; }
    public string QTD_CX { get; set; }
    public string QTD_TOTAL { get; set; }
    public string QTD_CX_PL { get; set; }
    public string QTD_UN_CX { get; set; }
    public int STATUS_ROMANEIO { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATA_ROMANEIO { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by rewriting the attributes name, in your class you're using like this: `ROMANEIO_ID`. Try rewrite to `romaneio_id`.

Comment: It worked.
I changed the name of the attributes, now everything is in lowercase.

PimBrouwers, Eduardo Nery, thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the CLR object you're asking Dapper to map to?

Does using ADO.NET directly yield the same result?

For example:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string")
{
   await conn.OpenAsync();

   using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TB_ROMANEIS", conn)
   using(var rd = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) 
   {
       while(await rd.ReadAsync()){
          var test = rd.GetValue(rd.GetOrdinal("STATUS_ROMANEIO"));
          //what does test == here?
       }
   }
}
```

It's also worth asking, because I think we've all made this mistake at some point. But are you absolutely sure the database shown in the picture is the one you're querying?

Comment: Hello PimBrouwers, thanks.

I tested the SELECT statement with ADO in another project and the result was correct, the name of the return column was the same as the name present in the database.

Comment: I have included the class used by Dapper right above.

Comment: That is incredibly strange.... Have you considered attached the dapper project and debugging? I've had to do it in the past when I noticed an issue with `uniqueidentifier`'s. It inevitably lead me to writing my own set of extension methods for `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Yes, very strange. I used the debugger, in the debugging attributes I show the current names of the columns, as in the database. But in the browser the name of the columns is different. I had changed the browser and used the Postman, but the result persists.
I do not know.

Is there anything that can cause this problem in the database or not? What do you think

Comment: What library are you using for serialization? Can you show that code?